# Matlab - Band-like diagram

Tags: matlab, plot, contour

I am trying to reproduce a band-like diagram, like the one in figure from windows defrag.

[image]

In principle, it can be easily obtained by doing a `contourf` of a matrix which is constant along one dimension (corresponding to the vertical dimension in the picture).

Do you know if there are *native* ways to obtain such a diagram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
vec = [1*ones(1,10), 2*ones(1,5), 3*ones(1,20), 4*ones(1,15)];

image('CData',vec, 'CDataMapping','direct')
colormap(lines(4))
axis tight off
```

or maybe even:

```
imshow(repmat(vec,10,1), lines(4))

imshow(vec, lines(4), 'YData',[0 10])
```

This is using an indexed image with direct color mapping, where the value `1` gets mapped to first color, value `2` mapped to second color and so on..  You can of course use your own colormap by specifying a N-by-3 matrix.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are requesting, but there is no specialised function in matlab to do this. However, you could easily implement your own function that uses `line` to draw a large number of lines based on your data. Using get/set on the handles of the lines would  let you control their colour, width etc. (also based on the input to your function).